# Where is the error? (C program won't print out the content of dynamic array)

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, dynamic

The task was to read the first 20 lines from a specific file and format them to use only specific parts, the next step was to store those formatted strings in a dynamic array (`char ** str` | a pointer to a pointer), send it to a function and print it out with said function

Here is the main code:

```c
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    FILE* file = fopen("./passwd.txt", "r");  // open file

    if (!file)
    {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }
    char line [MAXCHARS];
    int counter = 0;
    char ** str;
    str = malloc(20  * sizeof (char*));
    while (fgets(line, MAXCHARS, file) && counter < 20) {
        char * position;
        if ((position = strchr(line,':'))){
            char * end_char;
            *position = 0;        //setting here the value 0, will terminate the string line (first column)
            if((position = strchr(++position,':')) && (end_char = strchr(++position,':'))){ //increment the position to skip the second column
                *end_char = 0; //set the value 0 to end_char to terminate the string pointed by position
                char * temp_str = "\0";
                sprintf(temp_str, "{%d} - {%s}\n", atoi(position), line ); //concatenate line and userID into one string and store it into a temporary string
                *(str + counter) = malloc(sizeof (char) * strlen(temp_str)); //set the memory space for the temp_string into the array
                *(str + counter) =  temp_str; //copy the string into the array

            }
        }
        counter++;
    }

    printArray(str);

    fclose(file);
    if (line)
        free(line);


    return 0;
}
```

And here is the print function:

```c
void printArray(char ** array){
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        printf("%s",*(array+i));
        free(*(array+i));
    }
    free(array);
}
```

I cannot find the error, the code compiles with

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

So at least it compiles, and I think is just a problem in my pointers handling skills, but I'm not able to find the error.

Can someone help me?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `sprintf(temp_str,...` – you are printing into a string literal, which is undefined behaviour per se, moreover it is pretty likely that the non-writable buffer is too short as well...

Comment: `free(line);` is wrong: you don't allocated `line`

Comment: @Aconcagua, then how can i store with a specific format string? because the googling always brought me to the sprintf() function.

Comment: @Mathieu that free (line) was part of the previous task, jsut forgot to delete it

Comment: There's a short hand for `*(str + x)`: `str[x]` – but you are not *copying* into `str[counter]`, but instead re-assigning the temporary string, losing the pointer to the just allocated temporary, while the array would contain in all fields the same address of `tmp_str`. Instead you need to `strcpy(str[counter], tmp_str)` – or more efficient: `size_t len = strlen(tmp); malloc(tmp); memcpy(str[c], tmp, len + 1);` avoiding considering the null character multiple times (`strlen` and `strcpy`).

Comment: @SimoneNardone `sprintf` is fine – it is the buffer that is not. You need to allocate sufficient memory for, e. g. via `char tmp_str[MaximumExpectedLength];`. The format specifier for the string might consider a maximum string length if you want to be on the safe side (preventing writing beyond the buffer).

Comment: Okay thank u very much to all, i understood it now.

Comment: Side note: On a POSIX system you could use `strdup` for convenience – note that your code then is *not* portable, though (until C23, at least, which will include it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 3 errors in your program :

1. use temp_str which haven't allocated.

   ```
   char * temp_str = "\0";
   sprintf(temp_str, "{%d} - {%s}\n", atoi(position), line );
   ```
2. save `temp_str` local pointer's address  to `str+counter` and use the pointer after it went out of scope at `printArray`=> undefined behavior
3. `line` is not a pointer, can't use `free`

   ```
   if (line)
   {
      free(line);
   }
   ```

lets try this. https://godbolt.org/z/7KPfnTEMY I correct these points

Comment: Than the error was with the memory allocation, forgot to correctly allocate it,  Thank u very much.

Comment: Just to be precise: Storing the address of a local variable in an array is not undefined behaviour – but reading that pointer after that local variable has gone out of scope is...

Comment: And worse: `str[counter] = malloc(); str[counter] = tmp_str;` <- memory leak, last pointer to memory just allocated is lost.

Comment: @Aconcagua, yes, thanks, using  a pointer which went out of scope is UB. I'll correct it

Comment: @Aconcagua `printArray` will free them.

Comment: @long.kl Not in original version – the address of the newly allocated memory gets overwritten in the expression immediately following by assignment to `tmp_str` – `printArray` would try to free the temporary (multiple times!). This changes with your version, where you correctly `strcpy` the data from the temporary into that newly allocated memory.